# boost::python returning object array gives segmentation fault when exposing c++ function to python

Tags: python, c++, boost, boost-python

I wrote an interface using `boost::python`. There are two classes called `AA` and `BB` and BB has a function called `get_AA` which is return object array of `AA`. Here the code I have written.

**Class AA**

```
class AA{
    int height;

    //constructors
    AA(){}
    AA(map<string,string> data){}
}
```

**Class BB**

```
class BB{
   //constructor
   BB(std::string url){}

   //method
   AA * get_AA(){
      AA * blockRangeArray = new AA[SIZE];

      //getting data from SQL-Lite
      std::vector <std::map<string,string>>  rangeData;
      rangeData = xx.data();   //this works fine 

      for(int x = 0; x <= SIZE; x++){
            std::map<string,string> slaveBlkMap;
            slaveBlkMap = rangeData[x];

            Block *blk = new Block(slaveBlkMap);     
            blockRangeArray[x] = *blk;
      }

      return blockRangeArray;
   }
}
```

Here is my **BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE**

```
BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(mylib){
   using namespace boost::python;

   class_<BB>("BB", init<std::string>())
   .def("get_AA", &BB::get_AA, boost::python::return_value_policy<boost::python::manage_new_object>());

   class_< AA >("AA");
```

This creates mylib.so shared library. Then I used that in python. Like follows.

**run.py**

```
import mylib

data1 = mylib.BB("dfsfs");
AA_class_object_Array = data1.get_AA()  #expecting array of AA objects
```

But when compile and run, this code gives me an error of **Segmentation fault (core dumped)**.

Comment: Please try running the code with valgrind. It will give you more meaningfull information.

Comment: convert array of object to python list of object then only you can use it into python